# Can I put a paper from a non-indexed conference to Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, arxiv, google-scholar

I have a paper published in the proceedings of a student conference that is not indexed. Is it possible to add it to my Google Scholar profile? Can I submit it to Arxiv and then add to the Scholar profile?
I'm fairly new to the field and don't know all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** Yes, you may go to your profile, press to the "+" icon, and provide the bibliographic data of your contribution.
[![Plus icon and **Add article manually** menu item>] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdUEv.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdUEv.jpg)

**Question 2**: Yes, you could submit the paper to arxiv.org. Papers, which are included in arxiv.org are indexed in Google Scholar. Make sure that the copyrights of the proceedings of the student conference do not prevent publication via arxiv.org. Further, be aware that there is a kind of approval process in arxiv.org, i.e., not every submitted paper finnally gets published in arxiv.org.

Comment: As far as I understand, if it's the first publication, you don't have that "+" icon because going to "my profile" makes you choose an article from the search only

Comment: @ElonMuskofBadIdeas Yes, this might be true if there is no entry in the profile yet.